# Mathematic Javascript Computation

Tags: javascript

I have a list of number as below:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

how can I use javascript to search the answer for below equation without repeating the number twice

```
() - () = 1  
() + () = 9  
() - () = 2  
() + () = 7
```

Thank you

Comment: did you try anything? is this a HW?

Comment: Either come up with an algorithm or use brute force. But neither is specific to javascript.

Comment: Algorithm is the way to go , finding the "Best' algorithm is your challenge

Comment: is the input and output are always the same?

Comment: Find every combination that satisfies each line, sort lines by shortest number of possibilities, pick one possibility for first entry, remove those numbers, repeat for the rest of the lines

Comment: @PaulS. you just answered his question . let him implement it

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker Look very like a homework problem to me.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I agree , and he/she should work on it first

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker Well I think we can help him on conceptualizing how the algorithm might go and leave the coding writing part to him.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 that's exactly what i mentioned on a reply to pauls. comment. He gave him/her a guideline

Comment: nope... this is not a homework... its just an iq question i saw in website and come out an idea to come out the best algorithm for this.... i alr graduate more than 10 years ++ ..hihi ...

Comment: not sure heuristic search will works or not... i still trying, just thinking to ask anyone got any fast idea on this or not.

Comment: @ntc2000 If that's the case you probably want to post your (partial) solution here so people won't mistaken it as a homework problem.

Comment: the problem has no solution. (See my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to solve the problem with a brute force approach.

Make an array with 4 items.

Each item is all the solutions to one of the equations.

The solutions for an equation is an array of couples of numbers that satisfy the equation.

You end up having 7 solutions for the first equation, 4 for the 2nd, 6 for the 3rd, 3 for the 4th.

All the possible combinations are `7 * 4 * 6 * 3 = 504`

Check every solution for the first equation with all the solutions for the seconds and so on.... ...with four nested `for` loops. Verify that no numbers are used twice.

**The problem has no solution**

Here is a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/vxg9o78t/1/

Here is the code

```
solve();

function solve()
{
    // solutions

    var s =
        [    
            [
                [2,1],[3,2],[4,3],[5,4],[6,5],[7,6],[8,7]
            ],
            [
                [8,1],[7,2],[6,3],[5,4]
            ],
            [
                [3,1],[4,2],[5,3],[6,4],[7,5],[8,6]
            ],
            [
                [6,1],[5,2],[4,3]
            ]
        ];

    // counters

    var i0,i1,i2,i3;

    var n0 = s[0].length,
        n1 = s[1].length,    
        n2 = s[2].length,    
        n3 = s[3].length;    

    // configuration check

    var a,
        found,
        j,
        foundn;

    // check every combination of valid solutions

    foundn = 0;

    for( i0=0; i0<n0; i0++ )
    {
        for( i1=0; i1<n1; i1++ )
        {
            for( i2=0; i2<n2; i2++ )
            {
                for( i3=0; i3<n3; i3++ )
                {
                    // the array a is used to check how many times
                    // each number is used. Item nr. 0 is unused.

                    a = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
                    a[s[0][i0][0]]++;
                    a[s[0][i0][1]]++;
                    a[s[1][i1][0]]++;
                    a[s[1][i1][1]]++;
                    a[s[2][i2][0]]++;
                    a[s[2][i2][1]]++;
                    a[s[3][i3][0]]++;
                    a[s[3][i3][1]]++;
                    found = true;
                    for( j=1; j<=8; j++ )
                    {
                        if( a[j] > 1 )
                        {
                            found = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if( found )
                    {
                        console.log( s[0][i0][0] + ' ' +
                                     s[0][i0][1] + ' ' + 
                                     s[1][i1][0] + ' ' + 
                                     s[1][i1][1] + ' ' + 
                                     s[2][i2][0] + ' ' + 
                                     s[2][i2][1] + ' ' + 
                                     s[3][i3][0] + ' ' + 
                                     s[3][i3][1] );
                        foundn++;
                    }
                }    
            }   
        }    
    }

    console.log( 'found ' + foundn + ' configurations' );
}
```